# Comparing 1 cell to 3 other cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying compare a cell to 3 possible outcomes in a race. If the cell equals the value in the first cell they get 5 points, if the cell equals the value in the second cell they get 3 points, if the cell equals the value in the third cell they get 1 point. If the cell does not match any of the three possible cells they get 0 points. I have tried using the below but it has not worked

```
=IF(B4=$B$38,5,0)+OR(B4=B$39,3,0)+OR(B4=$B$40,1,0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use INDEX(,MATCH())

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({5,3,1},MATCH(B4,B$38:B$40,0)),0)
```

Another method is to use CHOOSE:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(B4,B$38:B$40,0),5,3,1),0)
```

Or just maths:

```
=IFERROR(7-MATCH(B4,B$38:B$40,0)*2,0)
```

The key with MATCH is that it returns the relative position that we can use with INDEX,CHOOSE, or just do math with it.

So if it is equal to the value in B40 it would return `3`.  The INDEX and CHOOSE would then return the third in the array of choices.  The math would return 1 `7-3*2`

If you want to use IF, then you can nest the IFs by putting the next in the false of the prior.

```
=IF(B4=$B$38,5,IF(B4=B$39,3,IF(B4=B$40,1,0)))
```

Or if you have Office 365 Excel you can use IFS:

```
=IFERROR(IFS(B4=$B$38,5,B4=B$39,3,B4=B$40,1),0)
```

Answer (score 2):

[The other Scott’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1301063/150988#1301065) is fine, but what you had is close to working. 
If you are ***absolutely, positively sure***
that the three base values are different, you can do

```
=IF(B4=$B$38,5,0)+IF(B4=B$39,3,0)+IF(B4=$B$40,1,0)
```